# Angular2 UI-Router, async transitionService.onBefore

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

How can I register ui-router transition hook using async function in the body? I need redirect to substate based on async result. This is my code, which does not works, because callback does not returns any value:

```
router.transitionService.onBefore({to: 'app'}, transition => {
    let dashboardService: DashboardService = transition.injector().get(DashboardService);
    dashboardService.getList().subscribe((list: Array<Dashboard>) => {
        if (list.length) {
            return transition.router.stateService.target('app.dashboard', {id: list[0].id});
        }
    });
});
```

The callback expects a return value to be TransitionHookFn. I tried return Promise and Subject but this caused an error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Observable must be transformed into promise:

```
router.transitionService.onBefore({to: 'app'}, transition => {
    let dashboardService: DashboardService = transition.injector().get(DashboardService);

    return dashboardService.getList().toPromise().then((list: Array<Dashboard>) => {
        if (list.length) {
            return transition.router.stateService.target('app.dashboard', {id: list[0].id});
        }
    })
});
```